# To prove that $\sup C=ab$

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets of positive numbers bounded above, and let $a=\sup A$ and $b=\sup B$. Let $C$ be the set of all products of form $xy$. where $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. To prove that $\sup C=ab$.

## My attempt

Now to prove existense of supremum is easy as it is based on lub axiom. I am writing about other part. Since $a_1 \leq a$ and $b_1 \leq b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

So multiplying two inequalities i get $a_1b_1 \leq ab$. This shows that $ab$ is upper bound for set $C$. Now to prove that it is least is main issue.

So i use contradiction by assuming that $K$ is least upper bound and so $K \leq ab$.

Since by assumption given in question i can write as
there exists some $a_1 > a - \epsilon$ and $b_1 > b - \epsilon$ (Because $a$ and $b$ are given to be supremum), epsilon is bigger than $0$

So i have now $a < a_1 + \epsilon$ and $b < b_1 + \epsilon$. Multiplying these i get $ab < a_1b_1 + a_1\epsilon + b_1 \epsilon + \epsilon^2$. So $K < a_1b_1 + \epsilon(a_1b_1)$. I think this is a contradcition

Please cross check my proof. Thanks

Comment: It's the right idea, but it needs something more. Specifically, you need to choose $\epsilon$ based on what $K$ is, not just as an arbitrary small number.

Comment: In last inequality i can chose epsilon to be some other $epsilon/a_1b_1$. I sthis what you are saying

Comment: A simpler idea is to say that if ab is not the supremum then there exist $a'b'$ where $a'\in A$ and $b'\in B$ such that $a'b'>ab$, It should be easy to reach a contradiction from here.

Comment: @Meadara Here $ab<a_1b_1$ + epsilon stuff. Is this what are you pointing to?

Comment: First of all you need $K<ab$, not $\leq ab$. Then what you need to do is to calculate $a_1b_1>(a-\epsilon)(b-\epsilon)$ and show that there is an $\epsilon$ such that $(a-\epsilon)(b-\epsilon)>K$, thus proving (in somewhat reverse order, but that's how it's usually done) that for any candidate $K<ab$ there are $a_1\in A,b_1\in B$ such that $a_1b_1>K$.

Comment: @Meadra He has shown that $ab$ is an upper bound. What you wrote in your comment is basically right there in the question body. The problem here is showing that it's the _least_ upper bound.

Comment: @Arthur if you also assume that $ab>a'b'$ you have an obvious contradiction so neither of our above assumptions were correct and as a result $supC=a'b'=ab$.

Comment: @Arthur I am assuming that $K <ab$. So to get $ab$ term should it not that i multiply to get $(a_1 + \epsilon )(b_1 + \epsilon) > ab$

Comment: @Meadara if you assume ab>a'b',and say supC is a'b',its wrong I think.its better to use"≤" like you do in your answer

Answer (score 1):

In the last step of your proof you said 
$K\le ab  <a_1b_1 + a_1\epsilon + b_1\epsilon + \epsilon^2$ 
But how far are you sure that $ab  <a_1b_1 + a_1\epsilon + b_1\epsilon$ ? or even that $K< a_1b_1 + a_1\epsilon + b_1\epsilon$ since $\epsilon$ could be any positive real number,In real analysis it is sometimes useful to visualise your result and try various means to achieve it so I suppose that your idea was to show that $ab\le K$ and that $ab\ge K$ inorder to show that $ ab = K $

Lets assume that ab is not the supremum then there exist $ a'b' \in C $ such that $ab \le a'b'$ .But $a \ge a'$ and $b \ge b'$ thus $\frac{a}{a'} \ge 1$ multiply by $\frac{b}{b'}$ we have $\frac{ab}{a'b'} \ge \frac{b}{b'} \ge 1$ and as a result $ab \ge a'b'$

On the other hand suppose that $ab \ge a'b'$ this is a contradiction since $a'b'$  is the supremum of the set C so $ab \le a'b'$

We have the 02 results $ab \le a'b'$ and $ab \ge a'b'$ we conclude that $ab = a'b'=SupC $

Comment: K is by assumption to be least upper bound and ab is also upper bound so K<ab. $ab < a_1b_1+(a_1+b_1)\epsilon$(by multiplication of two inequalities). Whats wrong with this?

Comment: @Gathdi $ab < a_1b_1 + \epsilon (a_1  + b_1) + \epsilon^2$ doesnt imply that $ab < a_1b_1 + \epsilon (a_1  + b_1) $ because $a_1b_1 + \epsilon (a_1  + b_1) \le ab$ could be true.

Comment: @Gathdi set C must contain ab ,then if you say k is least upper bound and k<ab,which means ab is not in set C.this is wrong is your comment.

Comment: @Meadara nice answer